# Collections.sort() declaration: why <? super T> rather than <T>

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparable

Why does [`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) have the signature :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

and not :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<? extends T> list)
```

- I understand that they both would serve the same purpose; so why did the framework developers use the first option?
- Or are these declarations really different?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your proposed signature would probably work in Java-8. However in previous Java versions type inference was not so smart. Consider that you have `List<java.sql.Date>`. Note that `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date` which implements `Comparable<java.util.Date>`. When you compile

```
List<java.sql.Date> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(list);
```

It perfectly works in Java-7. Here `T` is inferred to be `java.sql.Date` which is actually `Comparable<java.util.Date>` which is `Comparable<? super java.sql.Date>`. However let's try your signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<? extends T> list) {}

List<java.sql.Date> list = new ArrayList<>();
sort(list);
```

Here `T` should be inferred as `java.util.Date`. However Java 7 specification does not allow such inference. Hence this code can be compiled with Java-8, but fails when compiled under Java-7:

```
Main.java:14: error: method sort in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
        sort(list);
        ^
  required: List<? extends T>
  found: List<Date>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: Date
    bound(s): Comparable<Date>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T>sort(List<? extends T>)
1 error
```

Type inference was greatly improved in Java-8. Separate JLS [chapter 18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) is dedicated to it now, while in Java-7 the rules [were](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) much simpler.

Comment: But how does static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> c) works fine ...is this again a inference issue?

Comment: @prvn, here you have `Comparable<? super T>` instead of `Comparable<T>` like in your proposed signature. `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<? extends T> list)` would also work, but adding `? extends T` is completely unnecessary here, while reasonable in `max` method (as `max` returns the value).

Comment: There is another point. When you have a wildcard type like `List<? extends T> list` you can’t do `list.set(index, list.get(anotherIndex))` inside the method, due to how wildcard types work. This can be circumvented with an internal helper method capturing `? extends T` into another type variable (or by using unchecked operations as internal implementations often do), but still, a type without wildcards is cleaner for a list that is going to be modified.

Comment: @Holger: But that's an internal implementation concern for the implementor. We are just looking at the public API, which should not be affected by internal implementation details.

Comment: @newacct: if two variants make no difference to the caller, you’ll likely choose the one that allows an easier implementation. Nevertheless, developers got used to initially think that a parameter of a `List<? extends …>` type is not going to be modified due to the *PECS* rule and need a second look at the method if you use that for a `sort` method. It’s more than an implementation concern.

Answer (score 9):

```
// 0
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort0(List<T> list) 

// 1
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort1(List<? extends T> list)
```

These signatures differ because they impose different requirements on the relationship between type `T` and the type argument to `Comparable` in the definition of `T`.

Suppose for example that you have this class:

```
class A implements Comparable<Object> { ... }
```

Then if you have

```
List<A> list = ... ;
sort0(list); // works
sort1(list); // fails
```

The reason `sort1` fails is that there is **no** type `T` that is both comparable to itself and that is, or is a supertype of, the list's type.

It turns out that class `A` is malformed, because objects that are `Comparable` need to meet certain requirements. In particular reversing the comparison should reverse the sign of the result. We can compare an instance of `A` to an `Object` but not vice-versa, so this requirement is violated. But note that this is a requirement of the *semantics* of `Comparable` and is not imposed by the type system. Considering only the type system, the two `sort` declarations really are different.

Answer (score 4):

They differ because `? super T` is less restrictive than `T`. It is a [Lower Bounded Wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) (the linked Java Tutorial says, in part)

> The term `List<Integer>` is more restrictive than `List<? super Integer>` because the former matches a list of type `Integer` only, whereas the latter matches a list of any type that is a supertype of `Integer`.

Replace `Integer` with `T` and it means a `T` **or** a `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: but i am increasing flexibilty in the argument of sort() ..using  ? extends,

Comment: Yes, nobody said that `List<? super Integer>` is the same as `List<Integer>`. The second version uses `extends` and the question is if this makes it equal.

Comment: I don't think your answer is directly related the question.